# I just copy the code but got problem of "a symbole name was expected"

Tags: php, sql, xampp

[my code and the error][1]

I just started learning sql, right now cannot run my code although i just copy the code.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqYOQ.png

Comment: remove the comma `,` in the last element `address ...... NOT NULL,` and please post code not images (or only images) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Just try to remove last comma.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here][1]

remove this comma and try it
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAYXd.png

Comment: Please post as text not as picture.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).